# Estimote android nothing appear on oncreate

Tags: android, oncreate, estimote

Im using the code in github like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView rangeLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.range_label);
    final TextView beaconMacAddressLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.beacon_mac_address_label);
    final TextView beaconUuidLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.beacon_uuid_label);
    final TextView beaconVersionLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.beacon_major_minor_label);
    final TextView beaconStatsLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.beacon_stats_label);

    rangeLabel.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    rangeLabel.setText(R.string.question_mark);
    region = new Region("regionid", null, null, null);

    beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
    beaconManager.setRangingListener(new RangingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, final List<Beacon> beacons) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                      if (!beacons.isEmpty()) {

                          Beacon closestBeacon = beacons.get(0);

                          beaconMacAddressLabel.setText(getString(R.string.mac_address) + " : " + closestBeacon.getMacAddress());
                          beaconUuidLabel.setText(closestBeacon.getProximityUUID());
                          beaconVersionLabel.setText(getString(R.string.major) + ": "+closestBeacon.getMajor() +
                                                     "   " + getString(R.string.minor) + ": " + closestBeacon.getMinor());

                          beaconStatsLabel.setText(getString(R.string.power) + ": " +
                                                closestBeacon.getMeasuredPower() +
                                                " " +
                                                getString(R.string.dbm) +
                                                " |  " +
                                                getString(R.string.rssi) + 
                                                ": " + closestBeacon.getRssi());

                          double accuracy = Utils.computeAccuracy(closestBeacon);

                          switch (Utils.proximityFromAccuracy(accuracy)) {
                            case FAR:
                                rangeLabel.setText(R.string.cold);
                                rangeLabel.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cold_colour));
                                rangeLabel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cold_indicator_background);
                                break;
                            case NEAR:
                                rangeLabel.setText(R.string.warm);
                                rangeLabel.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.warm_colour));
                                rangeLabel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.warm_indicator_background);
                                break;
                            case IMMEDIATE:
                                rangeLabel.setText(R.string.hot);
                                rangeLabel.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.hot_colour));
                                rangeLabel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hot_indicator_background);
                                break;
                            case UNKNOWN:
                                rangeLabel.setText(R.string.question_mark);
                                rangeLabel.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                rangeLabel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.indicator_background);
                                break;
```

but after running, just the tittle, app name and rangeLabel appear on the screen.
Wonder why other textview such as beaconstatslabel... do not appear. Anyone know why, please help me. THank you all

Comment: please post your logcat output

Comment: Can you give your layout file also?

Comment: thank for your reply, this is my layout
https://github.com/KarlNosworthy/hotwarmcold/blob/master/HotWarmColdApp/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml

Comment: sorry sir, Im quite new for android, dont know what is logcat :(